# Integral and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Supose that $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x)dx=0 $$

$\forall n=0,1,2,...$. Proof that $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

These are the steps:

- Prove that for any polynomial $P$:
  $$\int_0^1P(x)f(x)dx=0$$
- Use  [the Stone–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)
- and finally use the fact that if *(since $f$ is continuous)*
  $$\int_0^1f^2(x)dx=0$$
  then $f$ is the zero function.